# anchor tag with JavaScript, inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript that outputs links (search results) but I'm having problems adding onclick in the anchor tag

```
var str = "<a href='#bokvisning' onclick='javascript:$(#bokvisning_content).load('http://www.akademika.no/node/"+item.link+"')'>" + item.title + "</a>";
```

It outputs this, which is wrong:

```
<a href="#bokvisning" onclick="javascript:$(#bokvisning_content).load(" http:="" www.akademika.no="" node="" link')'="">Title</a>`
```

Is it possible? What other options do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick fix is the quotes, like this:

```
var str = "<a href='#bokvisning' onclick='javascript:$(\'#bokvisning_content\').load(\'http://www.akademika.no/node/"+item.link+"\')'>" + item.title + "</a>";
```

It would be better to add the click handler unobtrusively though, like this:

```
var anchor = $("<a/>", {href:'#bokvisning', text:item.title}).click(function() {
   $("#bokvisning_content").load("http://www.akademika.no/node/"+item.link);
});
//or for older jQuery versions (<1.4):
var anchor = $("<a href='#bokvisning'></a>").text(item.title).click(function() {
   $("#bokvisning_content").load("http://www.akademika.no/node/"+item.link);
});
```

Then append *that* to whatever element you're currently putting the string in.

*Note:* The second option above assumes jQuery is an option because your `onclick` is using it.

Comment: +1 for always using DOM-like methods instead of unreliable and insecure HTML string-slinging—especially for event handlers, where you have multiple nested escaping contexts. However there is still an HTML injection hole here (potential XSS, if `item.title` is user-supplied). I suggest using the `$('<a href="#bokvisning">', {text: item.title})...` shortcut to avoid this.

Comment: @bobince - Good call, updated, though slightly differently, having attributes in the html string *and* the properties object [throws an error](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/297Cm/), though it really should be handled.

Comment: Oh! You're right, it's taking the `html, document` overload instead of `html, props`. I'd never noticed this, as I've always set every attribute from `props` like in your example. Oh dear! I wish jQuery didn't try to shoehorn *everything* into one `$()` property, this kind of value-level overloading is crazy!

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly escape the quotes:

```
var str = "<a href='#bokvisning' onclick='javascript:$(#bokvisning_content).load(&#39;http://www.akademika.no/node/"+item.link+"&#39;)'>" + item.title + "</a>";
```

I've replaced two apostrophes with `&#39;` inside your string.

Also, don't you mean `$('#bokvisning_content').load ...`, which would give us:

```
var str = "<a href='#bokvisning' onclick='javascript:$(&#39;#bokvisning_content&#39;).load(&#39;http://www.akademika.no/node/"+item.link+"&#39;)'>" + item.title + "</a>";
```

All in all, using @Nick Craver's solution to untangle the multiple layers of quoting might be best.